# Run Mysql in a docker container with Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to change my embedded in-memory H2 database to a MySQL instance using docker.

The application runs fine in-memory using docker, but I can't manage to change to MySQL.

I did some research, and managed to write this docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  #service 1: definition of mysql database
  db:
   image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql-db2
   environment:
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=sa
   - MYSQL_USER=password
   ports:
   - "3306:3306"

  #service 2: definition of phpMyAdmin
  phpmyadmin:
   image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
   container_name: my-php-myadmin
  ports:
   - "8082:80"
  restart: always

 depends_on:
  - db
 environment:
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: sa
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: password



  #service 3: definition of the spring-boot app
  customerservice:                        
 image: mysqldockerapp               
  container_name: mysql-docker-app  
 build:
  context: .                          
  dockerfile: Dockerfile              
 ports:
  - "8084:8084"                       

 depends_on:                           
  - db                                
 environment:
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql-db2:3306/customer?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: sa
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: password
```

And these are my application.properties

```
server.port=8084
spring.application.name=customer-service

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-db2:3306/customer?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never

logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

And my dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:16-alpine3.13
MAINTAINER krzysztof.com
EXPOSE 8084
COPY target/myapp.jar myapp.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/myapp.jar"]
```

The containers build correctly, but the app exits and I get:

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

But the MySQL container is running, so I would appreciate any tips where should I look for possible reasons.

Comment: If MYSQL is initializing the customer database `MYSQL_DATABASE=customer` is needed. If also possible that your app is giving up before MySQL as has started.

Comment: replace `mysql-db2` in the connection string with `db`

Comment: @danblack I've set the app to restart if the connection was not established(or any other exception) but it keeps on crashing couse of the above error

Comment: @Noami Yizraeli, did you mean, change the spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-db2:3306/customer?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC to spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db2:3306/customer?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC? Tried it and it noes noe yeld any results.